# Nova instância sobrescreve valores da antiga

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Deem uma olhada nessa classe:

```
class Signal:
    point = None
    view = {
        "x": None,
        "y": None,
        }
    def __init__(self, point):

        self.point = point

        self.set_position()

        print(self.point + " -> " + str(self.view["x"]) + "x" + str(self.view["y"]))

    def set_position(self):
        if self.point == "north":
            self.view["x"] = 150
            self.view["y"] = 200
        else:
            self.view["x"] = 300
            self.view["y"] = 400

    def check(self):
        print(self.point + " -> " + str(self.view["x"]) + "x" + str(self.view["y"]))
```

E agora no seguinte resultado ao instanciar 2 variáveis diferentes como esse objeto e checar os valores:

```
>>> s1 = Signal("north")
north -> 150x200
>>> s2 = Signal("south")
south -> 300x400
>>> s1.check()
north -> 300x400
```

Eu simplesmente não consigo encontrar a lógica disso. Podem me explicar pq ao criar a `s2` os valores da `s1` são trocados?

Comment: `view` é do tipo dicionário e está definida como variável da classe, não da instância: [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) (documentação em inglês)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso aqui...

```
class Signal:
    point = None
    view = {
        "x": None,
        "y": None,
        }

    ...

# fim da classe
```

...não faz o que você acha que faz. Declarar variáveis no topo da classe dessa forma faz com que elas sejam compartilhadas entre todos os exemplares da classe (semelhante ao `static` de outras linguagens). Para declarar campos na sua classe, o jeito adequado em Python é:

```
class Signal:

    def __init__(self, point):
        self.point = None
        self.view = {
            "x": None,
            "y": None,
            }

    # demais métodos

# fim da classe
```

Ou seja, incializá-los no construtor, colocando o mesmo logo no início da classe, para facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Python possui muitas cascas de banana pra que está saindo de outras linguagens. Muito obrigado pelo help.

Answer (score 2):

> Podem me explicar pq ao criar a `s2` os valores da `s1` são trocados?

Porque as variáveis `point` e `view` são atributos da classe `Signal` e não da instância.

Atributos de classe são atributos cujo proprietário é a propria classe, que serão compartilhados com todas as instâncias da classe. Para definir atributos exclusivos a uma instancia, defina as variáveis no [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

```
class Signal:
    def __init__(self, point):
        self.point = point
        self.view = { "x": None,
                      "y": None,
                    }

        self.set_position()

        print(self.point + " -> " + str(self.view["x"]) + "x" + str(self.view["y"]))
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/DYoc)</kbd>

Mais detalhes na [**documentação**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).